# Website change index directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, directory, server

I would like to put my website online. So far, my index.php file is in this directory:

> www.website.com/directory/subdirectory/index.php

My problem: The visitor should see the index.php when he visits www.website.com

How do I link / route the visitor to the subdirectory/index.php ? Otherwise I would have to change all links within my website. 
Thank you!

Comment: Simple question.. Why did you make your website 2 levels deep to begin with if you knew you wanted to serve it from the root?

Comment: Do you only need to access this page (the entire website is called by the user from this page) or do you have other pages that the user needs to access in this `directory/subdirectory` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Only this page to view:

Create a `.htaccess` file at the root of your website and in it, put:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) directory/subdirectory/index.php
```

This means that any request sent to the server will return what would be returned if we called `directory/subdirectory/index.php`.

You will need to adapt this if you want to get GET requests.

## Redirection:

Create a file `index.php` at the root of your website and in it, put:

```
<?php
header("Location: directory/subdirectory/index.php");
```

This will send the user to `directory/subdirectory/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your .htaccess

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

As it is right now, on default, when someone visits your website.com, index.html is currently the default.

You can change index.php to whatever the file is.